# Difference function Char / Chr in Delphi 2007 and XE3

Tags: delphi, unicode, char, delphi-xe3, chr

I am using function Char and Chr with parameter 130 and has behave different in Delphi 2007 e XE3.

Delphi 2007: Char( 130 ) or Chr( 130 ) - Result: Comma

Delphi XE3: Char( 130 ) or Chr( 130 ) - Result: #$0082

I problem resolve using AnsiChar( 130 ).

My question is if I have problems using the AnsiChar. Should I change Chr / Char by AnsiChar throughout the project?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on what you actually do. In most cases, I'd recommend embracing Unicode. By the way, if you are using Windows-1252, Chr(130) is NOT a comma ("," U+002C: COMMA), but "‚" (U+201A: SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK). That's two completely different things, both semantically and (in most fonts) visually!

Comment: About the update: No, in Windows 1252, chr(130) is NOT a comma! Not at all!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These two are slightly different:

- Char(130) is a [value typecast](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Value_Typecasts) rather than a function call. An integer with value `130` is converted to a `Char` with that ordinal.
- Chr(130) is indeed a function call. It invokes the [intrinsic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines) function [`Chr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Chr).

In both pre and post Unicode versions of Delphi, you can use the `Char()` and `Chr()` versions interchangeably. However, the results differ depending on the Delphi version you use.

For pre-Unicode Delphi, `Char` is an 8 bit ANSI character. For post-Unicode Delphi, `Char` is a 16 bit UTF-16 character.

Exactly how you should resolve this depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you wish to bury your head in the sand, and pretend that Unicode characters don't exist, then perhaps you want to replace all your use of `Char` with `AnsiChar`. And you'll also want to hope that your program is only ever run on a machine with a locale that maps character 130 onto that character. Do be aware that not all Windows ANSI locales do so.

However, I suspect that the right solution to your problem, whatever it is, will be to embrace Unicode, and use the UTF-16 encoding for that character. It is [SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK U+201A](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201a/index.htm). Write it like this in Unicode Delphi:

```
Chr($201A)
```

or like this:

```
#$201A
```

or like this:

```
'‚'
```

On the other hand, perhaps you actually do want a comma, noting that `AnsiChar(130)` is not a comma but is in fact a quotation mark.

If you want a comma ([COMMA U+002C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/002c/index.htm)), well that's easy:

```
Chr($002C)
```

or

```
#$002C
```

or

```
','
```

Some required reading for you: [Delphi and Unicode by Marco Cantù](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38980).

Comment: That text seems to miss http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/HIGHCHARUNICODE_directive_(Delphi)

Comment: @Arioch'The The code in this answer is not impacted by that directive.